# DATE Conversion in Snowflake does not work within CASE statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to achieve this

```
CASE
WHEN 
(DIM_TEST."TEST START DATE" <> '' 
OR DIM_TEST."EST START DATE" IS NOT NULL 
OR DIM_TEST."EST START DATE" <> 'NULL') 
THEN TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE(DIM_TEST."TEST START DATE", 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')

ELSE DIM_TEST."TEST START DATE"
END AS "FINAL_DATE"
```

It does not work

```
too many arguments for function [TO_DATE(DIM_TEST."TEST START DATE", 'YYYY-MM-DD')] expected 1, got 2
```

Any suggestions?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the source column data type is not string but rather DATE/TIMESTAMP

```
SELECT TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

> -- Error: too many arguments for function [TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE(), 'YYYYMMDD')] expected 1, got 2 (line 1)

The [TO_DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html) allows to use second argument only if the first argument is string:

```
TO_DATE( <string_expr> [, <format> ] )
TO_DATE( <timestamp_expr> )
TO_DATE( '<integer>' )
TO_DATE( <variant_expr> )
```

The entire CASE expression is probably not correct as the column is not string, and there are comparison against string literals `''` and `'NULL'`.

Finally, the first part of case expression tries to return string`TO_VARCHAR` but the second is an original column, thus the final data type will be the data type of the column.